# WordPress Multisite - how to activate groups of themes without having to network activate?

Tags: wordpress

I've got a single WordPress 3.1.3 multisite installation. Some sites need access to just a few themes, and some need access to all installed themes (150+). Right now I have it set so the only have access to the basics at start, then I have to manually go in an enable the other ~150 themes. Obviously, frequently clicking 150 checkboxes sucks.

Network activation doesn't allow me to deselect themes for specific sites. I've searched and searched for plugins to do this, but haven't found anything. The closest I've found is for networks, but I need it to be on a site-by-site basis.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to check 150 boxes. there is a single box at the top of the list and if you check it, all the boxes below get checked and the job becomes simple.

i use the same thing for my site http://latesthub.in

Comment: That only works for the themes on one page. There's no way to list more than 20 themes per page. So if I select that box, choose bulk actions... I can only do 20 at a time. So better than 150, but still rather tedious considering I may need to do this 20+ times a day.